# Change temp file location of QGIS in Ubuntu

Tags: files, environment-variables, tmp, environment, qgis

on a windows machine u can easily change the location where QGIS stores its temp files (see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156129/how-can-i-change-the-folder-location-for-qgis-temporary-files).

However, in Ubuntu I would not know which environmental variable to change. There is no Temp or Tmp variable indicated and there is also no variable linked to the path where I would expect the Temp files to be stored (which would be "/tmp"). See the image blow leading to the Settings > Options > System interface.

[image]

Comment: Usually the flow in Linux is use `TMPDIR` if set, if not default to `/tmp`. Try with `TMPDIR=/some/path`.

Comment: Had exactly the same question today. Did the option @muru mentioned worked? If so what did you enter in each specific column?